# The server didn't send back a proper XML response

Tags: asp.net, fckeditor

I'm using FCKEditor in that when "Browse Server" button is clicked the following error is thrown.

> The server didn't send back a proper
>   XML response.  Please contact your
>   system administrator.
>
> XML Request error: Not Found(404)
>
> Requested URL:
>
> /fckeditor/editor/filemanager/connectors/asp/connector.asp?Command=....

I'm developing and testing my website on IIS7 with .NET.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine that you need to ensure that you've configured FCK to use ASPX for the FileBrowserLanguage and QuickUploadLanguage rather than asp.

I've got this set in the CustomFckConfig.js file, rather than modifying the core FckConfig.js file:

```
// The following value defines which File Browser connector and Quick Upload
// "uploader" to use. It is valid for the default implementaion and it is here
// just to make this configuration file cleaner.
// It is not possible to change this value using an external file or even
// inline when creating the editor instance. In that cases you must set the
// values of LinkBrowserURL, ImageBrowserURL and so on.
// Custom implementations should just ignore it.
var _FileBrowserLanguage    = 'aspx' ;  // asp | aspx | cfm | lasso | perl | php | py
var _QuickUploadLanguage    = 'aspx' ;  // asp | aspx | cfm | lasso | perl | php | py
```

I can't imagine that IIS7 is configured to serve .asp pages these days - isn't it geared up for .aspx? Seeing as you've tagged this question asp.net, I assume that the rest of your site is running in .Net.

Answer (score 1):

We had same problem with our web site build in .net 3.5 and hosted on IIS7.
I found solution that helped us. We changed source code of fckeditor (small fix) and set response filter property to null. Bug was related to compression of server response in asp.net.
Article that helped us we found [HERE](http://www.icodefactory.com/lab/post/FCKEditor-with-ASPNET-Fix-The-server-did-not-send-back-a-proper-XML-response-error.aspx).
I hope it will help you too.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Been walking through --a very long walk I might add-- a lot of suggested solutions but never found one that would address my problem.

I kept on getting the same response:

> The server didn't send back a proper
>   XML response. Please contact your
>   system administrator.
>
> XML request error: OK (200)
>
> Requested URL:
>   https:.../fckeditor/editor/filemanager/connectors/aspx/connector.aspx?Command=GetFoldersAndFiles&Type=Image&CurrentFolder=%2F&uuid=1260177467559
>
> Response text:
>   window.location.replace("http:.../fckeditor/editor/filemanager/connectors/aspx/connector.aspx?Command=GetFoldersAndFiles&Type=Image&CurrentFolder=%2F&uuid=1260177467559

Until finally, I stepped closer, re-read the response again and noticed that the request and response are using different protocols.

FYI, the editor is implemented in a secure part of the site accessible by site admins only. We're using the [Ventaur component](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/WebPageSecurity_v2.aspx) that does the automatic switching of HTTP/HTTPS requests.

The images --we only need to upload/browser image types-- reside in a subdirectory that is also configured to use HTTPS.

This gave me an indication as to where the problem is coming from, so I proceeded to set the fckeditor directory to use HTTPS as well.

This finally worked and iI was able to upload/browse images.

Answer (score 0):

Using [FireBug](http://www.getfirebug.com), check what the response the server is sending back to you.

You can do this by checking the *Console Tab*, after clicking your 'Browse Server' button.

That way, you can see what exactly is being received from the server, so you'll be able to debug it.

Comment: When I use FireBug to see the respone. It has "HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found. The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.". I'm thinkg myself, is IIS configuration wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That means that either a URI mapping is not made, or a file is missing. It's trying to access a certain URI, but it cannot find it (404 status code).

Are you sure your installation/configuration is complete and correct?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Zhaph's comment, check the server encoding and make sure that jives with your FCKEditor configuration.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your fckeditor.dll is on the path of Bin folder 
and make sure you have a right version of it